# Getting a bot to mention the person who initiated the command

Tags: discord.js

I’ve tried following a few other tutorials but I keep getting something wrong. I’m trying to have the bot ping the person who initiated the command like this.
User: Ping
Bot: @user Pong

I wrote this but when i execute the command it comes out as `${msg.author}` Pong.

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === ".p1") {
    msg.channel.send('${msg.author}  pong');
```

I also tried this

```
client.on("message", msg => {
          if (msg.content === ".p1") {
            msg.channel.send(msg.author + “Pong”)
```

When i did this second one, the discord ID of the person initiating the command showed up but was not pinged

Ex: [string of numbers] pong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use backticks (\`\`)  for `${}` templates to work.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.author` is enough, you just need to change `""` to `backqoute`

```
client.on("message", msg => {
 if (msg.content === ".p1") {
     msg.channel.send('${msg.author}  pong'); // must be `${msg.author}  pong`
 }
```

If you only use `quote` or `double quote` you only passing a `string` that's why your mention is not working.

Comment: If it's a typo or clearly a duplicate, just write a comment and/or flag it as one.